# ParcelJS referencing files from DIS folder instead of the ROOT making it impossible to debug code

Tags: javascript, install.packages, parceljs

I cant debug my code because when I run dev mode, (npm run dev) the console is referencing the parcel js cloned file in the DIS folder.

This is not the expected behaviour. Parcel.js, in development mode should be referencing the original main.js file in the root folder.

I have ran another parcel.js installation on another mac to re-produce the same error, but parcel.js worked as expected, meaning this problem maybe isolated to my own mac. At this point i have no idea what to do.

I am a complete newbie.

Therefore I can't debug my code, look below where the errors are... its pointing to the cloned files in the DIS folder rather than my files in the ROOT folder.

[console window error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyEaP.png)

The console logs are pointing to the cloned main.js file in the DIS folder.

I've re-installed parcel several times, I don't know what i'm doing wrong here.

This is what my set up looks like.

[full view of my desktop and file structure, with console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2lrp.png)

- it should not be pointing too **main.1f19ae8e.js:121**
- It should be pointing to **main.js**

My package.json

[Package.json image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8gwX.png)

**Everything works as expected when i click debug in the package.json**

[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz9Ga.png)

[bug report in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6Y4p.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!!! I randomly tested it on fire-fox and it worked... so i switched off all my chrome extensions and tested it again...still didn't work.... then i decided to a clean reinstall of chrome and it worked! Guess i will never no the true fault. But my chrome install must of been buggy or something.

EDIT: True solution - Enabling this fixed the error.

[image]